# How to Set Up Application Insights from an Release Pipeline/ARM Templates

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-application-insights, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have an Azure DevOps release pipeline, which sets up all of our Azure resources in a location. I can create everything successfully with ARM templates, but I'm struggling to link the App Service with the App Insights resource.

If I were doing it manually, I'd click a "Turn on site extension" button in the AppInsights blade of the App Service (under the heading "Enable Application Insights through site extension without redeploying your code").

I've tried adding an "Azure App Service Manage" step to my release pipeline, set to install the "Application Insights extension for Azure App Service" extension:

[image: Screenshot of Release Pipeline Step for Installing AppInsights]

In addition, I've added an "Azure App Service Manage" step to my release pipeline, set to "Enable Continuous Monitoring":

[image: Screenshot of Release Pipeline Step for Enabling Continuous Monitoring]

But the result is still that AppInsights is connected, but the extension is not installed:

[image: Screenshot of Azure Portal showing extension is not turned on]

Is there any way I can do this automatically? Either via an ARM template, a PowerShell script, or something else?

**Edit:** In the "Extensions" blade, I can see "Application Insights extension for Azure App Service" (v2.6.5) and "ASP.NET Core Logging Extensions" (v2.2.0), but I'm still asked to "Turn on site extension" in the "Aplication Insights" blade.

Answer (score 13):

In an ARM-template you can do:

```json
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
  "name": "[variables('web_app_service_name')]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('plan_name'))]",
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('app_insights_name'))]"
  ],
  "kind": "app",
  "properties": {
    "siteConfig": {
      "appSettings": [
        {
          "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
          "value": "[reference(variables('app_insights_name'), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
        },
        {
          "name": "ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION",
          "value": "~2"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Refer to documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-web-apps#automate-monitoring

Comment: I had same issue with AppInsights not automatically enabled by ARM. I first added ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION=~2. Following above troubleshooting guide, i found IKeyExists = false. Setting APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY fixed IKeyExists = true. These two changes were sufficient to fix my issue.

Comment: See the response from @Alex-AIT below - the answer above required an additional app-setting for APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING before working for me.

Answer (score 2):

i think you would need to do something like that:

```
    {
        "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
        "name": "[parameters('webSiteName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "tags": {
            "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]": "Resource",
            "displayName": "Website"
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
            "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components/', parameters('appInsightsName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "name": "[parameters('webSiteName')]",
            "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
        },
        "resources": [
            {
                "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
                "name": "appsettings",
                "type": "config",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('webSiteName'))]",
                    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "[reference(concat('microsoft.insights/components/', parameters('appInsightsName'))).InstrumentationKey]"
                }
            },
            {
                // this bit installs application insights extension
                "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
                "name": "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites",
                "type": "siteextensions",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('webSiteName'))]"
                ],
                "properties": {
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

I've never actually tried this, but looks correct, link to the example I've found: https://github.com/tomasr/webapp-appinsights/blob/master/WebSite.json

Comment: I tried this, and I can see under the "Extensions" blade of the App Service "Application Insights extension for Azure App Service" (v 2.6.5), but the App Insights blade still says the same thing: "There is an update available for Application Insights site extension that provides a better experience", with a button to "Turn on site extension"

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your app settings key is `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` and not `ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey`. Somewhere in the MS docs it gives the impression that you can use either. In fact that's not the case, in Azure you *need* to use the former otherwise Application Insights won't be enabled for server side insights.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the Azure Portal to show an active integration with Application Insights, you need to set *three* app settings.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-web-apps?tabs=net#automate-the-creation-of-an-application-insights-resource-and-link-to-your-newly-created-app-service

```json
{
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[parameters('name')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "properties": {
                "siteConfig": {
                    "appSettings": [
                        {
                            "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
                            "value": "[reference('microsoft.insights/components/AppMonitoredSite', '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING",
                            "value": "[reference('microsoft.insights/components/AppMonitoredSite', '2015-05-01').ConnectionString]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                            "value": "~2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "name": "[parameters('name')]",
                "serverFarmId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'),'/resourcegroups/', parameters('serverFarmResourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
                "hostingEnvironment": "[parameters('hostingEnvironment')]"
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
                "microsoft.insights/components/AppMonitoredSite"
            ],
            "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]"
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
            "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
                "workerSizeId": "[parameters('workerSize')]",
                "numberOfWorkers": "1",
                "hostingEnvironment": "[parameters('hostingEnvironment')]"
            },
            "sku": {
                "Tier": "[parameters('sku')]",
                "Name": "[parameters('skuCode')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2015-05-01",
            "name": "AppMonitoredSite",
            "type": "microsoft.insights/components",
            "location": "West US 2",
            "properties": {
                "ApplicationId": "[parameters('name')]",
                "Request_Source": "IbizaWebAppExtensionCreate"
            }
        }
    ],
    "parameters": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "hostingPlanName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "hostingEnvironment": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "sku": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "skuCode": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "workerSize": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "serverFarmResourceGroup": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subscriptionId": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
}
```

See also my other answer on this: [Azure Cli How to enable Application Insights for webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63140378/azure-cli-how-to-enable-application-insights-for-webapp/63142868#63142868)