# Azure Cli How to enable Application Insights for webapp

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-cli, azure-webapps

Consider the following code. It creates an application insight, then it retrieves the instrumentationkey and assigns it to my webapp.

```
    az monitor app-insights component create -g $resourceGroup --app $webapp --application-type web --kind web --tags $defaultTags
    
    $instrumentationKey = az monitor app-insights component show -g $resourceGroup -a $webapp --query 'instrumentationKey' -o tsv
    az webapp config appsettings set -g $resourceGroup -n $webapp --settings APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY=$instrumentationKey APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING=InstrumentationKey=$instrumentationKey
```

However, this does not turn on application insight for the webapp as shown in this screen capture. I cannot figure out how to turn it on from azure cli.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set a couple more app settings to make it exactly like if you enabled it from the Azure Portal. I believe the second important key after the instrumentation key is `ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-web-apps?tabs=net#automate-monitoring

Powershell example which you can adapt to AzureCLI:

```bsh
$app = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "AppMonitoredRG" -Name "AppMonitoredSite" -ErrorAction Stop
$newAppSettings = @{} # case-insensitive hash map
$app.SiteConfig.AppSettings | %{$newAppSettings[$_.Name] = $_.Value} # preserve non Application Insights application settings.
$newAppSettings["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"] = "012345678-abcd-ef01-2345-6789abcd"; # set the Application Insights instrumentation key
$newAppSettings["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"] = "InstrumentationKey=012345678-abcd-ef01-2345-6789abcd"; # set the Application Insights connection string
$newAppSettings["ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION"] = "~2"; # enable the ApplicationInsightsAgent
$app = Set-AzWebApp -AppSettings $newAppSettings -ResourceGroupName $app.ResourceGroup -Name $app.Name -ErrorAction Stop
```

Answer (score 8):

Using the link @Alex AIT provided the cli could be as follows.

*Please note that you could also rely on the fact that if you don't create an App Insights instance an auto instance will be created and used.*

```bsh
# (...) Set up $plan, $resourcegroup and $region

az appservice plan create --name $plan --resource-group $resourcegroup --location $region --sku FREE

[String]$webapp="myapp"
az webapp create --name $webapp --plan $plan --resource-group $resourcegroup

[String]$appinsights=$webapp
az monitor app-insights component create --app $appinsights --location $region  --resource-group $resourcegroup

# Get the instrumentation key 
# '--output tsv', which is 'Tab-separated values, with no keys'
# is used to obtain the unquoted value
# as shown in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#get-a-single-value
[String]$instrumentationKey = (az monitor app-insights component show --app $appinsights --resource-group $resourcegroup --query  "instrumentationKey" --output tsv)

# Configure the app to use new app insights instance
# Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-web-apps?tabs=net#enabling-through-powershell
az webapp config appsettings set --name $webapp --resource-group $resourcegroup --settings APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY=$instrumentationKey APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING=InstrumentationKey=$instrumentationKey ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION=~2
```

Comment: can you explain how an auto instance would be created?

Answer (score 3):

There is a better approach than trying to manually set the app settings. Simply use this command (Link to docs provided):

```
az monitor app-insights component connect-webapp --app
                                             --resource-group
                                             --web-app
                                             [--enable-debugger {false, true}]
                                             [--enable-profiler {false, true}]
```

[Connecting an application insights to a web app.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/app-insights/component?view=azure-cli-latest#az_monitor_app_insights_component_connect_webapp)