# why does app insights need to be turned on manually after automated release?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, appinsights

**Why doesn't app insights turn on automatically after the release?**

After executing the automated release, I'm getting this when navigating to app insights in the portal:

[image]

Here's how I've defined this in my ARM template:

```
{
  "type": "microsoft.insights/components",
  "kind": "web",
  "name": "[parameters('webAppName')]",
  "apiVersion": "2015-05-01",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "tags": {
    "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('webAppName'))]": "Resource",
    "displayName": "[parameters('webAppName')]"
  },
  "properties": {
    "Application_Type": "web"
  },
  "dependsOn": []
}
```

What am I doing wrong? **Why isn't app insights automatically turned on?**

Please note that I've added the following appsettings:

[image]

Comment: Did you look at any sample ARM templates with app insights integration for web apps? They include additional appsettings that contain necessary things such as the instrumentation key. You can even export an ARM template from the portal for a web app that's configured correctly and discover what you're missing.

Comment: @DanielMann thanks for that comment, i've updated the question to show the setting that i've added

Comment: Please go **actually look at a sample ARM template**. The key you added isn't correct.

Comment: thanks. i'll update the key to APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY

Comment: @DanielMann havent been able to figure this out. gut shabbos

Comment: @AlexGordon, is this issue solved now?

Comment: @IvanYang it is not.

Comment: @DanielMann the answer is complete below. please have a look and enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer is outdated. It's not recommended to use APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY with APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING. Whichever is provided last wins.

Using instrumentation key is deprecated, we should transition to using APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING instead.

Otherwise provided answer holds true. More info here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/migrate-from-instrumentation-keys-to-connection-strings

Comment: your answer is wrong. as of 13.02.2023, If you don't set up the APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY the insights won't be linked with the app as seen in Azure Portal. Original Alex AIT answer is still correct, both settings are required.

Comment: Can you provide information how the answer is wrong? We have already moved to APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING without any issues on production workloads.

Comment: I think this answer is correct.  Refer to this page, which states reliability, security, privacy improvements of using a connection string:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/migrate-from-instrumentation-keys-to-connection-strings

Comment: Do you call add application insights in code?

Comment: Documentation is wrong. Until I added the APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY string it didn't work, simple as that. I am leaving this comment, so someone hitting this issue wont get frustrated. Azure is ever changing so it might be resolved now, but I have no time to check.

Answer (score 10):

In order for the Azure Portal to show an active integration with Application Insights, you need to set *two* app settings. The reason is that you also need to configure the Application Insights Agent Extension.

Note that setting the InstrumentationKey(deprecated) or connection string might be enough for your application to send telemetry to ApplicationInsights, e.g. if you are using ASP.NET Core and the corresponding Nuget package. But you will need both settings for the portal to show the active integration.

```json
{
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[parameters('name')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "properties": {
                "siteConfig": {
                    "appSettings": [
                        {
                            "name": "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING",
                            "value": "[reference('microsoft.insights/components/AppMonitoredSite', '2015-05-01').ConnectionString]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                            "value": "~2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "name": "[parameters('name')]",
                "serverFarmId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'),'/resourcegroups/', parameters('serverFarmResourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
                "hostingEnvironment": "[parameters('hostingEnvironment')]"
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
                "microsoft.insights/components/AppMonitoredSite"
            ],
            "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]"
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
            "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
                "workerSizeId": "[parameters('workerSize')]",
                "numberOfWorkers": "1",
                "hostingEnvironment": "[parameters('hostingEnvironment')]"
            },
            "sku": {
                "Tier": "[parameters('sku')]",
                "Name": "[parameters('skuCode')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2015-05-01",
            "name": "AppMonitoredSite",
            "type": "microsoft.insights/components",
            "location": "West US 2",
            "properties": {
                "ApplicationId": "[parameters('name')]",
                "Request_Source": "IbizaWebAppExtensionCreate"
            }
        }
    ],
    "parameters": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "hostingPlanName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "hostingEnvironment": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "sku": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "skuCode": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "workerSize": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "serverFarmResourceGroup": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subscriptionId": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
}
```

See also my other answer on this: [Azure Cli How to enable Application Insights for webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63140378/azure-cli-how-to-enable-application-insights-for-webapp/63142868#63142868)

Edit: updated based on the new information in the answer by BearOakheart.

Comment: please update based on the answer below

Answer (score 0):

I had to set up 4 app settings for it to automatically register and turn on app-insights (using bicep in this case):

```
{
  name: 'APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING'
  value: applicationInsights.properties.ConnectionString
}
{
  name: 'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'
  value: applicationInsights.properties.InstrumentationKey
}
{
  name: 'ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION'
  value: '~3'
}
{
  name: 'XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Mode'
  value: 'recommended'
}
```